# JGit merge Repo A into forked version repo B, where A is ahead of B

Tags: java, git, github, egit, jgit

```java
final Git repoAgit = Git.cloneRepository()
            .setURI(repoAgitUrl)
            .setDirectory(new File(repoApath))
            .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/develop"))
            .setBranch("refs/heads/develop")
            .setTransportConfigCallback(TRANSPORT_CONFIG_CALLBACK)
            .call();
final Git repoBgit = Git.cloneRepository()
            .setURI(repoBgitUrl)
            .setDirectory(new File(repoBpath))
            .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/develop"))
            .setBranch("refs/heads/develop")
            .setTransportConfigCallback(TRANSPORT_CONFIG_CALLBACK)
            .call();
```

How do I merge `repoA` into `repoB`, where `repoA` is supposed to be ahead of `repoB`, and `repoB` is a forked version of `repoA`?

Answer (score 0):

First, in `repoB`, create a remote that references `repoA`.

Then fetch from this remote so that there are two local branches: `refs/heads/develop` and `refs/remotes/repoa/develop`.

If not yet done, checkout the target branch `refs/heads/develop` in repoB.

Call the `MergeCommand` to merge the remote tracking branch into HEAD.

For example:

```java
repoB.remoteAdd().setName("repoa").setUri(new URIish("/path/to/repoA")).call();
repoB.fetch().setRemote("repoa").call();
MergeResult mergeResult = repoB.merge()
    .include(repoB.getRepository().resolve("refs/remotes/repoa/develop"))
    .call();
```